# Django models: Datetime auto_now only on changing specific field

Tags: python, django, datetime, model

I have a django model with several columns and these two:
 - is_completed (boolean)
 - completed_datetime (datetime)

Now I want to update the datetime field automatically when is_completed is changed. Is there an simple way for this? Auto_now won't work, because I don't want to update the datetime field when other fields than is_completed are updated.

Comment: you can override the models' `save` method to achieve this

Comment: That's what I did right now. Is that the best way?

Comment: Yes. That is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

Override the model save method:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):

   def save(self, *args, **kw):
       if self.is_completed:
           self.completed_datetime = timezone.now()
       super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: I guess OP wants on change, not if true.

Comment: @karthikr: That's right, I guess the name is_completed is a bit confusing.